# Force class reloading when the module is reloaded

Tags: python, python-2.7, sage

In my client code I have:

```
import sys
import os
YAP_PATH = "/package/src/python"
if YAP_PATH not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(YAP_PATH)

if 'yap' in sys.modules:  
    reload(yap)

import yap

print "working dir", os.getcwd()
```

(it's a development environment for sage, so don't yell about the hacky solution)

And in my module's `__init__.py`:

```
import Repository

__all__ = ['Repository']

print "yap loaded"
```

This prints "yap loaded" every time I evaluate the first code block (in a sage cell), so the module gets really reloaded every time.

What I want to achieve now in `__init__.py` is that every time the module is reloaded, the class `Repository` to also be reloaded.

How to achieve that, without putting code in the sage cell, but in the `__init__.py` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, maybe someone finds it helpful:

```
from Repository import Repository

__all__ = ['Repository']

def main(path):
    import sys
    _module_ = sys.modules[__name__]
    if hasattr(_module_, 'WORKING_PATH'):
        for m in __all__:
            if __name__ + "." + m in sys.modules:
                m = sys.modules[__name__ + "." + m]
                reload(m)
    else:
        _module_.WORKING_PATH = path

if __name__ == 'yap':
    print "yap loaded"
```

Patches welcome